# Magento 2 : how to use TinyMCE v4 in Magento 2.2.6?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, tinymce

I want to use TinyMCE Editor Version 4 in Magento version 2.2.6 Which are use in magento version 2.3.1.

If any one have solution then Pleas Provide me..

[image: TinyMCE v3]

in place of
[image: TinyMCE v4]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen this

https://github.com/pavelleonidov/magento2-tinymce4

This should work.  Only for Magento 2.1 and 2.2

Comment: How can i use this ?

Comment: @BhaveshPrajapati explain manual install?

Comment: thank u it work for me

Answer (score 3):

Run below commands to use that version.

```
composer config repositories.magento2-tinymce4 git git@github.com:pavelleonidov/magento2-tinymce4.git;
composer require pavelleonidov/module-tinymce4
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: i have manualy installed it but how it works ?

Comment: Did you redeploy static content and clear cache ?

Comment: i had run all commands s:upg, s:s:d -f, i:rei, c:f